# Is there a way for a Generic object to have no Generic type?

Tags: swift, generics

Is there currently a way for a generic class/struct to have no data type?

For example I have these two sets of api results.

#### result 1

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success"
}
```

#### result 2

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "result": <Some Result Here>
}
```

Here's my example data model

```
public struct APIResult<Result> {
    public let status: Int
    public let message: String
    public let result: Result?

    // I want some kind of init like this
    // note: I do data parsing a different way this is just an example
    init(status: Int, message: String, result: Result?) {
        self.status = status
        self.message = message
        self.result = result
    }
}
```

Is there a way for **result 1** to have its own custom initializer like how other datatypes are made for example

```
extension APIResult where Result: SomeClass {
    init(...) {
        ...
    }
}

extension APIResult where Result == SomeStruct {
    init(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Note**: I know there is a different approach to this by creating a `protocol` for `APIResult` which only contains `status` and `message`, I'm just asking if there is a different way without doing so.

Comment: Would setting default `nil` value for `result` parameter be acceptable here?

Comment: @user28434 no because the type would then be `APIResult<_>` and that throws an exception on build time

Comment: That's just because you're not telling it the type: `let x = APIResult<String>(status: 0, message: "x", result: nil)`. Now `result` is `nil`, but `Result` is `String`. Is there something else you're missing?

Comment: But that's not what I want to happen, I want the result `APIResult<THIS>` to have no data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just remembered that actually `Swift` has actually built-in `EmptyResult` class, and it's called `Void` or `()` (Proper CS name is [`Unit type`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type)).

So, your extension should be like this:

```
extension APIResult where Result == () {
    init(status: Int, message: String) {
        self.init(status: status, message: message, result: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh, so I don't have to do something hacky like creating a struct/class called `EmptyResult`. I didn't know I could've just used `Void` all along